# How to make windows7 file explorer like winXP

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there a simple way of getting windows7 file explorer back to a nice, clean, simple, consistent explorer like it was in winXP?

I'm fed up with adjusting folder columns et al. and clicking on "apply to all folders" for nothing to happen. I just want a list of files with the columns I select and I don't want the column order to be continually reset.

Why do microsoft always tamper with things for the worse then take away the options to get it back :(

Comment: @duDE, My question is different to that one but it has pointed to some good alternatives to crappy explorer so I'll close as duplicate.

Comment: what question? it looks like "dude" deleted his comment so your comment doesn't make sense. Hence it's important to quote people. (though dude is most in the wrong here). Can you paste the link he was talking about? Or better, include the link in your question stating why yours is different. Or give the link and close yours. Either way give the link.

Comment: this one http://superuser.com/questions/309470/how-can-i-get-the-windows-xp-explorer-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

i'll post this as an answer because comments aren't great for pictures.

In my case it is rather like with xp

I click the bottom left which is like start(the orb in win7), then Computer and this comes up

[image]

And I click C and this comes up

[image]

So perhaps you can explain if that's what you want.. say if you are not getting that. Give screenshots of what you are getting, and we'll see exactly what the problem is. Maybe your problem is a setting isn't sticking for some reason. Show it with screenshots.